# How can I create index file while making the file format is lzo in hadoop using java

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

How can I create

> index file

while making the file format is lzo in hadoop using java mapreduce.

Comment: Can you add details about what you tried to do, and what happened?

Comment: I have a java code to compress my text input to lzo output.     job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
    job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
    
    FileOutputFormat.setCompressOutput(job, true);
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputCompressorClass(job, LzopCodec.class);
  And I set the output path. I dont know how to create a index file for the output .lzo file. Could anyone help me out?